# serial dilution

Tags: biology

If $0.01$ is $10$ to the negative 2nd power then what is $0.2$?

I am having trouble making all the test tubes a number that can be added together.

Test tube A is $.01 = 10$ to the negative 2nd power

Test tube B is $.1 = 10$ to the negative 1st power

Test tube C is $.2= $?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm).  $$\log_{10}(0.2)=-\log_{10}(5) \approx -0.69897$$

so $$0.2 \approx 10^{-0.69897}.$$